# How to go to other page without reloading with Router.navigate in Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I have a button in a component template. When clicked a component method is called with this code:

```
saveAndGoToDetails()
{
     // TODO: Here will be saving
     this.router.navigate(['/details/1029']);
}
```

It is called from a component with this part:

```
 <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="saveAndGoToDetails()">Save and go to details</button>
```

What it should do is navigate to this route without reloading whole app. In spite of this it reloads whole page when going to the URL.

How to navigate properly from a component to other route without reloading a page in Angular 7?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] on stackblitz. This isn't normal and should be reproduced so that we can tell you what's wrong : `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Comment: Is this button inside a form? Like a Submit button or something?

Comment: If you've put your action on <a> tag with a href then the behaviour is normal, same goes with submit button as suggested by @SiddAjmera.

Comment: hello, please don't request close of this question, because it will render it impossible to update the question and i will need to create a new one

Comment: I have updated the question with information how it is called. It is a normal button (not submit) and not a a href, what makes it odd

Comment: where is this button placed, in a form? If so, how does the form look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add:

```
return false
```

in the

```
saveAndGoToDetails()
```

handler function. The issue is caused by the way Angular Material forms work. If a button is placed in it. Even if it is not a submit button, Angular Material handles it as submit.

Comment: All buttons in Html are `type=”submit”` by default. It's not just in Angular. You could change the type to "button" to get around it

Answer (score -1):

First import

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

Then,
Add private route: ActivatedRoute inside your constructor as

```
constructor(..., private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

Then you can use the below function

`this.router.navigate(['details', '1029'], {relativeTo: route, skipLocationChange: true});`

Comment: You need to write a detailed answer.

Comment: i try this and get information: Cannot find name 'route'

Comment: Use (private route: ActivatedRoute) inside your constructor